# Categorical Scatter Plot with Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-express

I am trying to draw a scatter plot with numerical x-values that are discrete. The problem is that `Plotly` interprets the values as continuous and the resulting dots are not evenly spaced. In `Seaborn` I could solve this problem by converting the x-values to `str`, but this doesn't work in `Plotly`. Any solutions? MWE below:

```
4489058292    0.60
4600724046    0.26
6102975308    0.19
6122589624    0.10
4467367136    1.67
6008680375    2.50
4588967207    0.21
4941295226    0.34
4866979526    0.18
4906915418    0.38
```

```
test_df = pd.read_clipboard(sep="\s+", names=["ID", "Value"], index_col=0)

fig = px.scatter(
    test_df,
    x=test_df.index.astype(str),
    y=test_df,
)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

Comment: The expected output is just one in which the x-values are treated as categorical so that the dots are evenly spaced. I’ll add the expected output in a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, in the `update_layout`, you can specify the `xaxis_type` to be `category` like:

```
fig = px.scatter(
    test_df,
    x=test_df.index, #no need of str here
    y=test_df,
)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, 
                  xaxis_type='category') #add this
```